# Real difference between 'reference' and 'db.table_name'

Tags: foreign-keys, data-access-layer, web2py

I am having a probelm with web2py foreign keys, as this is lack of documentation on this its pretty fustrating. I define tables in different files most tables are related. I used to use db.table_name to denote foreign keys, but I was told to use 'reference tbl_name'. This however makes no difference whatsoever, I still get errors compalaining about models defined in later files as per alphabetical order rules for web2py. It seems it actually matters having tables in order, rendering the use of reference key word useless at best. Or am I missing somethng here.

Comment: I think you are missing something, but it's hard to say unless you provide the errors you are seeing along with code that can be used to reproduce them. The `reference tbl_name` syntax does allow you to reference tables that are not yet defined, so your problem must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are using `mysql`. In such case, it is a `mysql` error. `mysql` raises error no 150 (foreign key error). So, it is a database backend issue rather than a `web2py` problem. Please do check the documentation for your database server. How I solved the issue is in the `db.py` file declare (`db.define_table`) all the primary tables that require no foreign keys first and then continue declaring the tables that require the foreign keys (Just ensure that the foreign table exists before referencing it). In case you are using individual files for different tables in the `models` folder, then try finding out which tables are primary and make sure that they are created first by prepending the filenames with numbers so that before referencing a foreign key in a table, the 'foreign' table will already be existing in the database.

However, there should be no issues with `sqlite`.